# ASP.NET (C#) Graph

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph, stock

I am wondering how can I remove the 3 horizontal red lines on the stock graph as shown in image bellow.  Please ignore the dots/squares on the image they are irrelevant. I think I have searched every google page there is and went through every option asp.net has... and could not figure out it.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Code that generated this graph:

```
Double[] test = new Double[] { 10, 50 };

    Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Stock;
    Chart1.Series[0].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
    Chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
    Chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 10;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.Series[0]["PixelPointWidth"] = "5";

    Chart1.Series.Add(new Series("Test Series"));
    Chart1.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
    Chart1.Series[1].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
    Chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.Black;
    Chart1.Series[1].BorderWidth = 3;
    Chart1.Series[1].MarkerSize = 15;

    Chart1.Series.Add(new Series("New Series"));
    Chart1.Series[2].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
    Chart1.Series[2].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
    Chart1.Series[2].Color = Color.Orange;
    Chart1.Series[2].BorderWidth = 3;
    Chart1.Series[2].MarkerSize = 15;

    Chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new Double[] {-10, 50});
    Chart1.Series[1].Points.Add(25);
    Chart1.Series[2].Points.Add(20);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(test);
        Chart1.Series[1].Points.Add(25);
        Chart1.Series[2].Points.Add(20);
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code for the chart.

Comment: ok, I added the code that generated the picture above

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood.  Please edit your question and clarify that you are trying to remove the red horizontal lines.  I'll look at the question again in a few hours to see if I can contribute anything worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after looking into it obsessively, I think that I have a solution.  Just adding the two Y values, the chart has a default value of zero for a marker (high or low?).  By specifying that you will add the four values (open, close, high, low - not certain about the high/low order), you can hide those lines by making them fall within your open/close range, and by setting the PixelPointWidth to equal or less then your BorderWidth.

```
// IMPORTANT: add the ", 4" to indicate that you have the four Y values
Chart1.Series.Add(new Series("Stock", 4)); 
Chart1.Series["Stock"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Stock;
Chart1.Series["Stock"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
Chart1.Series["Stock"].Color = Color.Red;
Chart1.Series["Stock"].BorderWidth = 10;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

// Set <= BorderWidth, so that it's effectively hidden
Chart1.Series["Stock"]["PixelPointWidth"] = "10"; 
Chart1.Series["Stock"].Points.AddY(10, 50, 20, 30); // open, close, high, low.
```

That was a little hard to track down.  Whew.

Comment: So basically you are using border to hide the high and low?

Comment: Yes.  I couldn't find any option to remove that default line, so declaring high and low, then hiding them seemed to be the best option.

Comment: that is a brilliant workaround.  Thank you I will accept this answer since I cannot find the option to remove the line either.

Comment: Glad I could help, especially since I had misunderstood the first time around.  Information about that chart was so sparse which made me want to figure it out.  I couldn't find anything about that default line.  Hiding the lines has satisfied me, so now I can move on.  :)